# What prefix to use for command level booting of Ubuntu 20 from a bootable USB?

Tags: usb-drive, grubrescue

My Acer Aspire One which worked fine and could dual boot to either Ubuntu 18 or Windows 8, has now crashed. From the  command line that now appears, I can use a series of commands to get to the Ubuntu dual boot menu by setting the root and prefix and "insmod normal" for the hard drive partition sda5 where Ubuntu is installed. (ls shows "hd0,msdos5" as sda5 the partition where Ubuntu is installed and "/boot/grub" "insmod normal" works. But it doesn't boot to Ubuntu and it seems sda5 might be corrupt. I want to boot from a bootable USB key, which seems to be called (hd1,msdos3) using "ls" from the grub rescue boot terminal line. However using prefix=(hd1,msdos3)/boot/grub it doesn't find whatever it needs to boot from the USB. I'm very much a newby here but I suspect if I could identify the correct prefix and insmod parameters it might work. I know the USB key is bootable as I've installed Ubuntu 20 on my wife's computer with it.
Can anyone guide me here?
Bob Thomson
Ottawa, Canada

Comment: Wheat version of Ubuntu? 18 or 18.04 or 18.10. Also I do not think you mean Ubuntu 20, maybe 20.04 or 20.10.

Comment: The Acer Aspire I'm trying to recover has/had Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS on it. The bootable USB I used to successfully install Ubuntu on my wife's new computer is 20.04.1. If I am able to get into Ubuntu 20.04.1 on the USB key on the Acer Aspire, I hope to be able to use it to access and save/backup the files on the Ubuntu 18.04.5 partition on the Acer Aspire to another 128 GB USB key, then install Ubuntu 20 on the Acer Aspire. I will overwrite the Windows 8 that's on the Acer Aspire now as I never use it and prefer to not have Microsoft there at all anyway.